# Django: Intercepting & Accepting/Rejecting Login Attempts

Tags: django, django-2.2

Is there a way to intercept login attempts with Django, perhaps a signal or hook, whereby if a certain User attribute is True or False, would either allow the login attempt to continue, or reject it...

I would rather not have to rebuild from scratch, just use the existing Django infrastructure...

Maybe creating a custom `Permission` object programatically: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this. Probably the easiest is to create a custom auth backend which subclasses the built in ModelBackend but overrides [`user_can_authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.user_can_authenticate) to check your custom attribute.

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyCustomBackend(ModelBackend):
     def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        return user.is_active and user.my_custom_attribute
```

Then put this at the top of your AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS setting.

Comment: Great this works - but how would we customise the message returned ... e.g., the message in the Django Admin section?

Comment: Ignore that actually, it is out of scope for this question.